# Where is "Script" in Atom?

Tags: python, atom-editor

I am importing plotly.offline in my basic.py file, but when i run this basic.py in the platform-ide-terminal, an error comes up and says, `ImportError: No module named plotly.offline`.

I am sure plotly is pip installed. When i checked it in the default Terminal in my Mac,

```
pip show plotly
```

it reads,

```
Name: plotly
Version: 4.3.0
Summary: An open-source, interactive graphing library for Python
Home-page: https://plot.ly/python/
Author: Chris P
Author-email: chris@plot.ly
License: MIT
Location: /Users/Lorentz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: retrying, six
Required-by: dash, chart-studio
```

My default python in Terminal is 3.7.

So i am trying to set the default python of my Atom to 3.7. I googled and my answers are suggesting to set it through `Atom→Preferences→Open Config Folder, and open.atom/packages/script/lib/grammars/python.coffee`. This is from the official site https://atom.io/packages/script

But my problem is, under packages, i can't locate script.

[image]

i then tried to locate it from top menu, still no luck.

[image]

Would anyone please tell me where to locate the python.coffee file? or where actually is this "script"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go [here](https://atom.io/packages) and search for script. When it is found click install. Or go [here](https://atom.io/packages/script) and click install.

There is a file named init.coffee in the home/.atom directory. I don't know of a python.coffee file.